# How to create a source and destination worksheets in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, automatic-update

I am struggling with an excel feature regarding creating a **Source** and *Destination* workbook.

My **Source data** comes from the web. So I download it, create few new columns and functions and use it to make a dashboard on Power BI.
This dashboards needs to be updated as and when data on my source changes.

Since I have to make few changes to the **Source** data before making dashboards on Power BI, I cannot directly link the data for automatic updates.

The idea here is to create a *Destination* excel sheet with all necessary columns to connect on Power BI. And then download the Source file and create a link.
In this way I should be able to download new **Source** File every week which will update my *Destination* file and finally update my dashboards!!

How can I make this happen? I am not excel expert and really need help!!

PS I am using office 365, Excel version 2102

Comment: In what format is your internet data? CSV or HTML? Try playing around with the Data ribbon > From Web and > From Text options. Both these functions create live links to the source data (either on the web or from a file). In the connection properties, you can set an update frequency, and/or a "refresh on open". There is also an option to copy adjacent formulas downwards along the imported data (as the number of rows will vary based on the source). You can also manually refresh by clicking Data > Refresh all. In the same workbook, but new sheet, rework the data and link to Power BI.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
As far as I understand, my source data cannot be linked directly with From Web or From text options because it is neither CSV/HTML.
It is basically from web, where I have to download the file to be able to view it. This file is excel format.

Therefore, I need to download new files every week, recreate the columns and then recreate the dashboards to present the updated information.

So I am looking for a method to remove the process of recreating the worksheet with my new Source data every week. But rather link a source & destination file to make it less manual.

Answer (score 0):

So the question as I understand it is actually three questions:
(a) how to link to another Excel file,
(b) how to link to an Excel file that is on the web (without downloading it manually), and
(c) how to update the references if my linked Excel workbook is changing all the time?

**(a) Linking to another workbook on my computer**

With both workbooks open on you computer, go to the destination cell and type =, then switch directly to source workbook and click/select the source cell, and hit enter. Excel will update the formula in the destination cell to something like this:

```
='[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

or this

```
='C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

If you want to duplicate a whole column of data from the source sheet, edit the formula and change it to a relative reference:

```
='C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1
```

Now copy and paste/drag the formula down to duplicate cell by cell.

Notes:

1. Excel will actually store a physical copy of the data inside the destination file, so even if the source is unavailable, the destination spreadsheet will be working. If you reopen the file (especially on a different computer), Excel should ask if you want to update the source data.
2. You can change the source location or name of the file easily, by simply clicking Data ribbon > Edit links, then "Change Source"

**(b) Linking to another workbook that is stored on a web server**

You can manually type in the URL to the source file, just like you would the file path for a local file, e.g. (note this was a random working test file I could find on the web from a seemingly reliable source, use at own risk):

```
='https://docs.collectiveaccess.org/images/6/68/[Sample_data.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1
```

To start, I would suggest you set up your destination workbook using a local file first, then use the "change source" option to link to the web copy (simply paste the URL in the open file dialog box that pops up). Follow the same process weekly if the filename is changing.

**(c) Dynamic references to a source workbook**

To complicate the file linking further, lets say your source data is changing ever so slightly every week. An extra column gets inserted somewhere, or the sheet name changes etc. There are a few ways we can handle this using either a simple (yet manual) "search and replace" of formula text across the spreadsheet, or named ranges in the source file, or relative named ranges in destination file.

Lets say you link to SALES data in sheet1, column C in a source spreadsheet:

```
='[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C1
```

The next week the source spreadsheet has changed slightly and the same data column is now sheet2 column D.

**Method 1:** Hit Home ribbon > Find & Select > Replace (or shortcut key CTRL + H). In the *Find what* textbox put `[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C` and in the *Replace with* textbox `[test.xlsm]Sheet2'!D`, then click *Replace All*.

**Method 2:** Define a named range in the source file. Open the source file and select column C. Now Click Formulas ribbon > Define Name, and give the *name* `SALES`. Under *Refers to* Excel should have filled in `=Sheet1!$C:$C` because of the selection. Now in the destination workbook, say in B1, enter `='[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!SALES` and copy downwards. Note this is relative as `=SALES` in e.g. B100 will return the value in `'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C100`. Now, if and when the location of the SALES data changes, simply update the named range under Formulas > Name Manager.

**Method 3:** Define a relative named range in the destination workbook (in cases where you don't have prior access to the source file). Select the first cell in the DESTINATION sheet e.g. B1 where the SALES data must go. Now Click Formulas ribbon > Define Name, and give the *name* `SALES` and under *Refers to* enter `='[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C1`. Now in B1 enter `=SALES` and copy down column B. NB note the placement of the $ sign. This named range is relative to the row number your cursor is in when you defined the name. If you use `=SALES` in cell B100 it will return `'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C100`. If you use `=SALES` in cell G101 it will return `'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C101`. If you want to reference whole multi-column ranges together (say SALES and TOTALS columns are always next to each other), you can leave out the $ sign in the *Refers to* entry. Then `=SALES` in cell B100 will return `'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!C100`, but `=SALES` in cell C100 will return `'[test.xlsm]Sheet1'!D100`. Again, you can update the named range in Data ribbon > Name Manager to its new location in say Sheet 2 Column D when required. TAKE NOTE: relative names ranges don't play nice if you insert rows or columns. `SALES` will stay relative to the hardcoded reference B1 after the insert. Using the $ as above safe guards at least against column inserts.