# How to create a Destination file that is linked to a Source on Excel offline?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, automatic-update

I am struggling with an excel feature regarding creating a **Source** and *Destination* workbook.

My **Source** data comes from the web using which I must create dashboards on Power BI. But before that, I make few changes to the **Source** data such that it is suitable for Power BI and represents certain information.

Since I have to make these changes to the **Source** data , I cannot directly link the data for automatic updates on Power BI. (Using from Web option)
And also my Source data is updated with new rows every week.

So the idea here is to create a *Destination* excel sheet with all necessary columns to connect on Power BI. And then download the **Source** file and create a link.

With the help of this link, every week when I download new **Source** data report, and refresh my *Destination* file, it should get updated with the new rows.

And as the *Destination* file will be linked to Power BI, my dashboards will also be updated with new information.

How can I make this happen? I am not excel expert and really need help!!

PS I am using office 365, Excel

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here:

[How to create a source and destination worksheets in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1636252/how-to-create-a-source-and-destination-worksheets-in-excel/1637626#1637626).

Please comment on the answer on that link if it does not address your question.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I was unable to access that question, hence had to post again.

I tried the solution and it did give few great insights but it did not solve the entire problem.

1. When I use the "=" sign to directly link the Source worksheet to Destination worksheet, I can no longer convert the Destination worksheet to a Table (#SPILL appears when I insert Table). And due to this, I cannot connect this data to Power BI (as the data must be in a Table to work in Power BI)

Comment: 2. There is no direct URL to the Source workbook, therefore i cannot use the web option.

3. The Source workbook is updated with new rows every week and no columns are shifted. I add new columns to Source workbook to make it represent certain data in Power BI. 
So, what I need is to be able to have new rows updated to the Destination file. And also to have it updated in the additional columns.
In this way, the manual process of creating a new file every week can be eliminated.
I am afraid I need to use Macros for it, but don't really know how.

Comment: That spill error in your table is the actual problem. Perhaps you should rework this question "How to link to external workbook within Excel table without getting spill error". Take some screenshots of the workbook, step by step, as you link to the data and convert to table and get the error. Also google / create a new question "how to auto fill down columns if linked source workbook is updated with more rows". One way of doing this is to save you source xls as csv. Then import data > from text and set properties ~"Fill down adjacent columns".