# Blocking certain rows for certain users when sharing an excel-sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

This year, I will finish a master I've been doing and enjoyed, and we, the participants, would like to stay in touch after the course ending. We already have the WhatsApp Group, but it's difficult to store here information about every participant, especially if this information changes over time without the others knowing, so we thought about creating an Excel-archive following the typical model:

- Each column contains some subject (Name, Surname, Date of Birth, Hobbies, etc.)
- Each row belongs to a single user where he/she should fill in their information regarding the respective subject

[image]
[Stupid example, but I hope you get an idea.]

I am the one who should organize this document. Since some of the topics we've chosen for the columns may vary over time (e.g. Hobbies, the Company we're working for, phone number, etc.), the participants should be able to edit that information, which is easily attainable if I share the online-doc with everyone of them. The problem is that it is always *dangerous* to have someone (say A) who could modify the information of B without B knowing about that — it sometimes happens that you accidentally delete something without noticing —. Since I am the one responsible for the project, I should be able to edit everything (nonsense otherwise).

In order to solve the problem, I thought of the following solution:

> Every row should be blocked in the following way except for me: The user A gets something (say a key, a link, etc.), such that it can only modify cells in A's row. The participant B gets something (say a key, a link, etc. different than that of A), such that it can only modify cells in B's row. And so on.

I was wondering if this is possible, and if so, *how?* If not, what are the alternatives you would suggest? (By the way, I have Excel 2016, but know people who have access to other versions.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect say the header row from editing by anyone, but as far as I know per-user-cell-protection does not exist in either Excel or Google Sheets.

The easiest would just be to trust everyone in your group to only edit what they must. Accidental changes or deletions can in most cases be recovered by the admin user by looking at cell or file history and reverting back to previous data.

If you really wanted to, you could share individual files with each user (which only they have access to and can edit), then link that content to the read-only shared main file. Or you could use google/microsoft forms so users can submit their personal data via a form, which updates to a spreadsheet. Editing existing data is difficult, and in most cases the users would have to retype all their data and submit a new if any one detailed changed.

Lastly you could look into coding VBA or Google App Script to unlock certain cells if the user entered an access code (which you would have to generate, handle and authenticate manually in your code).

Comment: Thanks! I think that creating an individual file for every participant might be the best idea. I've been doing some tests and had one question. I have to excel documents stored in my Dropbox-account. The thing is, that I don't know how to link one cell (say A1) from the first doc to another cell of the second doc. If it wasn't online and used the desk-app, I would simply type `=` in doc 1's cell A1, then switch to the second document, and press on the desired cell. But this doesn't seem to work with the online file on dropbox. Do you know how I could do it?

Comment: Hi do checkmark this question as answered if it helped you. As for linking to an online workbook, have a look at option (b) in this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1636252/how-to-create-a-source-and-destination-worksheets-in-excel/1637626#1637626. Do provide feedback if you manage to implement this.

Comment: One potential caveat with the individual spreadsheets solution - the master sheet is read-only and will only be editable by you/admin. In order to update the master sheet, you/admin would need to open the master sheet (after an individual sheet was updated) and refresh the links/resave. There is perhaps a small chance that if you give everyone full edit rights, but also protect all the cells with a password, that everyone can do the master sheet update. In addition, everyone should have read-access to everyone else's individual sheets in order to update. Just guessing here...